# WYSIWYG Editor not working properly

Tags: magento-1.9.3.6

WYSIWYG Editor in Magento stopped working, when I click on show/hide editor, the insert image button disappears and nothing happens
[image]

[image]

I am unable to figure out the issue, I am using Magento ver. 1.9.3.6

these are the content management settings 
[image]

and one thing that is also weird now that if I edit a product no default tab comes, I have to select it. previously spec tab open my default. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any third party module, check any jQuery add into that module?

if yes it is conflict js issue, then you need to solve it.

Comment: how do i check that

Comment: check page source of that page

Comment: but I haven't installed any third party extention

Comment: are you sure? have you enable js merge?

Comment: i did but then i set it as no

Comment: based on product edit screenshot you are using some module